# Sticky buttons are moving down other content

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have three sticky buttons, that should scroll with the content.
From a functionality standpoint, everything works but for some reason, the three buttons seem to move the content down (see the big space above of "Prozess").

[image]

When I remove the buttons, the content moves up:

[image]

I can't figure out how I can have the buttons available but the content not moving down.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is an excerpt from the html & css:

```css
.container-sticky {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: $swica-white;
    z-index: 990;

    button, a {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 180px;
    }
}

.container-sticky__top0 {
    top: 0px;
}

.container-sticky__bottom0 {
    bottom: 0px;
}

.container-sticky__move-left {
    display: block;
    transform: translate(-10%, 10%);
// in my real code this is transform: translate(-100.5%, 500%); but with that, the buttons disappear here on stackoverflow
    height: 2.5rem;
}

.container-idx-2 {
    top: 2.5rem;
}

.container-idx-3 {
    top: 5.5rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container ">
            
<div class="form-row w-100">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Projekt</h2>
        <h4>Ändern</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <div>* = zwingende Felder (zum Speichern)</div>
        <div>** = fachliche Pflichtfelder</div>
    </div>
</div>



<hr class="hr-margin color-dark-gray">

<div id="app">
  <form action="/redacted" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">      
  <div class="container-sticky container-sticky__top0 container-sticky__move-left">
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Zum Portfolio</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container-sticky container-idx-2 container-sticky__top0 container-sticky__move-left">
            <button id="btn-back" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button">Zurück</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container-sticky container-idx-3 container-sticky__top0 container-sticky__move-left">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="submit">Speichern</button>
        </div>
    
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col-10">
      <h5 class="col font-weight-bold mt-4">Prozess</h5>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div> 
  
    <p class="col mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>

</form>
</div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is the right behavior for `sticky`

Comment: @dippas is there a way to get the buttons to stay on the page while scrolling without it affecting the other content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container.only_this {
padding-left: 154px;
}
.mt-4, .my-4 {
margin-top: 0rem!important;
}
div#app form {
display: flex;
}
.sticky_div {
  min-width: 140px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -154px;
  height: fit-content;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
div#app {
display: flex;
}
.container-sticky {
position: sticky;
background-color: $swica-white;
z-index: 990;
}
button, a {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: 180px;   
}
.container-sticky__top0 {
top: 0px;
}

.container-sticky__bottom0 {
bottom: 0px;
}
.container-sticky__move-left {
display: block;
/*transform: translate(-10%, 10%);
transform: translate(-100.5%, 500%);*/
height: 2.5rem;
}
.container-idx-2 {
top: 2.5rem;
}
.container-idx-3 {
top: 5.5rem;
margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="container-fluid">
<div class="container only_this">
    
<div class="form-row w-100">
<div class="col">
<h2>Projekt</h2>
<h4>Ändern</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-auto">
<div>* = zwingende Felder (zum Speichern)</div>
<div>** = fachliche Pflichtfelder</div>
</div>
</div>



<hr class="hr-margin color-dark-gray">

<div id="app">
<form action="/redacted" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">      
<div class="sticky_div">
<div class=" container-sticky__top0 container-sticky__move-left">
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Zum Portfolio</a>
</div>
<div class="container-sticky container-idx-2 container-sticky__top0 container-sticky__move-left">
    <button id="btn-back" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button">Zurück</button>
</div>
<div class="container-sticky container-idx-3 container-sticky__top0 container-sticky__move-left">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="submit">Speichern</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Content_Side">
<div class="row pt-3">
<div class="col-10">
<h5 class="col font-weight-bold mt-4">Prozess</h5>
</div> 
<div class="col-2"></div>
</div> 

<p class="col mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p class="col mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p class="col mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p class="col mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p><p class="col mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
</div>

</form>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have given the class "container-sticky" to the parent div which contains the buttons and the title "Prozess". Removing the "container-sticky" class from that div should do the job.

Comment: The container-sticky class is only on the buttons, not on the parent div